# Accord.net: Multilabel classification issue

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, multilabel-classification, accord.net

I am trying to upgrade my code for multi-label classification from version 3.0.2. to 3.3.0. I did the upgrade, but it seems that classification results were much worse now - algorithm is not able to classify many more instances than before. Can you please tell me if there is any issue in my new code. How to use estimated parameters for gauss kernel as I did before?

Old code:

```
var gauss = Gaussian.Estimate(inputs, Convert.ToInt32(inputs.GetLength(0) * 0.8));  

// Create the machine.
this.machine = new MultilabelSupportVectorMachine(inputs[0].Length, gauss, outputs[0].Length);
// Train the model.
var teacher = new MultilabelSupportVectorLearning(this.machine, inputs, outputs);
teacher.Algorithm = (svm, classInputs, classOutputs, i, j) => new SequentialMinimalOptimization(svm, classInputs, classOutputs) { UseComplexityHeuristic = true, CacheSize = 1000 };
teacher.SubproblemFinished += SubproblemFinished;
var error = teacher.Run(true);

// Save the model.
this.machine.Save(modelPath);
```

New code:

```
var gauss = Gaussian.Estimate(inputs, Convert.ToInt32(inputs.GetLength(0) * 0.8));
// Create the machine.
this.machine = new MultilabelSupportVectorMachine<Gaussian>(inputs[0].Length, gauss, outputs[0].Length);


// Create the multi-class learning algorithm for the machine
var teacher = new MultilabelSupportVectorLearning<Gaussian>(this.machine)
{
// Configure the learning algorithm to use SMO to train the
//  underlying SVMs in each of the binary class subproblems.
Learner = (param) => new SequentialMinimalOptimization<Gaussian>()
{
            // Estimate a suitable guess for the Gaussian kernel's parameters.
            // This estimate can serve as a starting point for a grid search.
                    UseKernelEstimation = true,
                    UseComplexityHeuristic = true,
                    CacheSize = 1000                    
                }               
            };
            teacher.ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1;
            // Learn a machine
            machine = teacher.Learn(inputs, outputs);
            Serializer.Save(machine, modelPath);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi - if you are still experiencing the issue, please post an example of the dataset you were using and the performance you were getting to the project's issue tracker. Having a reproducible example is the first step to get the issue fixed, thanks a lot in advance!